# The Period of Data Using TI-BASIC

Tags: math, calculator, trigonometry, period, ti-basic

I'm in basic trigonometry and currently learning how to find equations having been given the data only. I understand the concept pretty well, but I usually make a program in a TI-BASIC for solving my homework because it helps me understand it at a deeper level and gain an appreciation for the beauty of math, however this time I'm stumped. Is there a known way to take pure data and find it's period or frequency in a way that can be fully automated on TI-BASIC?

I think I have some potential solutions:

1. If I can figure out getting a mode on a TI-84 I can just figure out the space between the two numbers who are a part of the mode.
2. Safely decrease the range of the numbers to make the data more manageable, such as making the numbers between -1 and 1 and finding the space between 1 and the next 1
3. Guess probable equations and just figure it out through brute force

An example would be finding the period on [This Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wexU.png), hopefully, this makes sense, and if there isn't a known way that's okay. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Are you trying to fit the data exactly or only approximately? If the latter, you are looking at a regression problem, in context a [sinusoidal regression](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/301194/294695) problem. Perhaps this will help (even though it is in terms of a TI-89 rather than a TI-84): https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/ti-89-regression/

Comment: Oh my goodness that was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!!! In the lesson, it never said that this is what it's called, this was my first time asking a question on stack overflow and it got answered in a wonderfully straightforward way.

Comment: @JohnColeman : If your comment appeared to answer the asker's question, you should add it as an answer.